# check if result is in query before running vba expression

Tags: ms-access, vba

In an MS Access 2010 database, I have a navigation subform that has a few textboxes whose values are populated from an underlying query, and one textbox that is calculated.  I want to add some conditional logic to the calculated textbox.

Two of the populated textboxes are ClientNumber and DOB.  In the expression builder, the calculated textbox is Age and is currently calculated as follows:

```
=DateDiff("yyyy",[DOB],Now())+Int(Format(Now(),"mmdd")<Format([DOB],"mmdd"))
```

I would like to change the Age calculation to become something like the following pseudocode:

```
=IiF( 
    ClientNumber IN qryActiveClients, 
    DateDiff("yyyy",[DOB],Now())+Int(Format(Now(),"mmdd")<Format([DOB],"mmdd"))  ,
     "NA"
    )
```

***Can someone show me how to change this pseudocode so that it becomes actual working code to accomplish the desired task?***

For reference, qryActiveClients is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ActiveCustomers.FirstName, 
    ActiveCustomers.LastName, 
    tblClientAddress.HomePhone, 
    ActiveCustomers.ClientNumber
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            Clients.ClientNumber, 
            Clients.FirstName, 
            Clients.LastName, 
            (         
                SELECT COUNT(ReferralDate) FROM IntakeTable              
                WHERE Clients.ClientNumber =  IntakeTable.ClientNumber 
                AND Len(ReferralDate & '') > 0 
            ) AS IntakeCount, 
            (         
                SELECT COUNT(ExitDate) FROM ExitTable              
                WHERE  Clients.ClientNumber = ExitTable.ClientNumber 
                AND Len(ExitDate & '') > 0            
            ) AS ExitCount FROM Clients
    )  AS ActiveCustomers 
    INNER JOIN tblClientAddress 
    ON ActiveCustomers.ClientNumber = tblClientAddress.ClientNumber
    WHERE (((ActiveCustomers.IntakeCount)>[ExitCount]) AND ((tblClientAddress.CurrentResidence)=True));
```

Please note that qryActiveClients is not the same query as what the other controls are populated from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
=IIf( 
    DCount("*", "qryActiveClients", "ClientNumber=" & [ClientNumber]) > 0, 
    DateDiff("yyyy",[DOB],Now())+Int(Format(Now(),"mmdd")<Format([DOB],"mmdd")),
    "NA"
    )
```